# how to make 3g video calls in android

Tags: android, videochat

I am developing an application which contain SMS, Audio Calls and Call Log history. But also i need to add video calls to my applications. I tried a code as below, but It throws ActivityNotFoundException.
Please help me to make video calls.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
                callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(callIntent);
```

Any help will be appriciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the **object's reference** is `null`:

```
if(acode == null || acode.equals("")) {

}
```

the condition is true if acode is null or if is not null and is equal to an empty string.
In addition, android you can use

```
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(acode)) {
   }
```

that checks both for null and empty string, making your if condition more compact. From the documentation of `isEmpty`

> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution, taking into account that you are developing on Android, would be:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(acode)) {
    // do something here
}
```

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(acode)
```

and check for both empty and null strings

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**

if( acode !=null || acode.lenght()==0)
{
  //equals null your code 
}
else
{
  //not equals null your code
}